# How to get sitecore users and the custom profile properties information using solr, sitecore core index

Tags: solr, sitecore-api

How to Get Sitecore Users and Their Profile Information using Sitecore Solr core index. I am having huge performance issues when I using the below sitecore api's. so I want to know whether this can be achieved through sitecore solr core index.

```
RolesInRolesManager.GetUsersInRole(Role.FromName("Buyer"), true).Where(x => x.Profile.GetCustomProperty("Assigned Accounts").Contains("25011")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to rework your code by using `RolesInRolesManager.IsUserInRole` method instead - it is cache-based, which might help you to resolve performance issues.
On one of our previous projects that did resolve a quite similar case.
I hope, that was helpful for you.